# Deadline exceeded error when inserting attachments into Google Drive - Java

Tags: google-app-engine, drive

When there are more attachments and in the process of adding all into the google drive from the code there is an exception with the below description.

```
com.google.apphosting.api.DeadlineExceededException
```

A problem was encountered with the process that handled this request, causing it to exit. This is likely to cause a new process to be used for the next request to your application. If you see this message frequently, you may be throwing exceptions during the initialization of your application. (Error code 104)

Using the below code to save the attachments into Google Drive.

```
 public File insertFile(Drive service, String title, String description,     String mimeType,String parentId , String filename, byte fileByteArray[],
        HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
    throws MessagingException, ParseException, InterruptedException
{
    try
    {
        File body = new File();
        body.setTitle(title);
        body.setDescription(description);
        body.setMimeType(mimeType);
        if(parentId != null && parentId.length() > 0)
            body.setParents(Arrays.asList(new ParentReference[] {
                (new ParentReference()).setId(parentId)
            }));
        com.google.api.services.drive.Drive.Files.List files = service.files().list();
        FileList fileList = (FileList)files.execute();
        List fileArray = fileList.getItems();
        log.info("fileArray"+fileArray);
        log.info("file Array Size"+fileArray.size());

        File file=null;
        try{
         file = (File)service.files().insert(body, new InputStreamContent(mimeType, new ByteArrayInputStream(fileByteArray))).execute();
        log.info("-----------File----------"+file);
        System.out.println("FileName="+MimeUtility.encodeText(file.getTitle()));
        System.out.println("File URL"+file.getAlternateLink());
        System.out.println("File ID"+file.getId());

        return file;
    }
    catch(DeadlineExceededException e)
    {
         log.info((new StringBuilder("An error occured: ")).append(e).toString());
         //inserted for attachment saving error

         System.out.println("inside exception deadlineexception");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        log.info((new StringBuilder("An error occured: ")).append(e).toString());

    }
    return null;

}
```

Can someone suggest a way to optimize the code so that all the attachments say around 10 to 15 can be saved into the google drive without any exception.

Comment: How are you adding the files ? Is it from a User Interface ?